# checkbox on checked state changes header text

Tags: javascript, checkbox, controls

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
<label for="chk"></label>
<h1 id="header">Lorem ipsum</h1>
var chk = document.querySelector('#chk');
var header = document.querySelector('#header');
if(chk.checked)
    header.innerHTML = "state 1";
else
    header.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum";
```

So. when checkbox is checked text in  changes to "state 1"
when unchecked(default state) text returns to "state 2". 
This code isnt working what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi Bro!**

`<input type="checkbox" id="chk">
<label for="chk"></>
<h1 id="header">Lorem ipsum</h1>`

`

```
var chk = document.querySelector('#chk');
var header = document.querySelector('#header');

chk.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    if(chk.checked)
        header.innerHTML = "state 1";
    else
        header.innerHTML = "state 2";
});
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function myFunction(mycheckbox, label) {
        document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = mycheckbox.checked ? "state 1" : "state 2";
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this, 'header');" />
<label for="chk" id="header">Lorem ipsum</label>
```